# Fix the stemma codicum (forest tree)

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, trees

I created the following tree in LaTex using the forest package. However, there are still a couple of things that I cannot manage to fix. Could you please help me? Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
cut/.style={
    tikz+={
      \path [decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position .5 with {\draw [] +(90:2.5pt) -- +(-90:2.5pt);}}] ()  -- (!u);
    }
  },
nice empty nodes/.style={
for tree={calign=fixed edge angles}, delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,
for current and siblings={anchor=north}}{}}
},
  }
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[$\Omega$, nice empty nodes[[G][B, cut]]
[, cut
[H]
[, calign=last[A][R]]
[ceteri, cut]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

In the picture, I highlighted in red the things that I cannot fix. I would need a second cut on the line (the one on the right) and center the black line (the one linking R)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the additional cut, we change the definition of `cut` a bit: we make it accept an argument for position, and make the argument default to `0.5`. To add another cut, we can then simply use `cut` key again, with a non-default argument, below `cut=0.3`.

To align the empty node connecting `A` and `R` to its parent, we use `calign with current` on it. This key is a shortcut to saying `calign=child˙ (align with a certain child) and` caling child=2` (this is the certain child) at the parent node.

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  cut/.style={
    tikz+={
      \path [decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position #1 with {\draw [] +(90:2.5pt) -- +(-90:2.5pt);}}] ()  -- (!u);
    }
  },
  cut/.default=0.5,
  nice empty nodes/.style={
    for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},
    delay={
      where content={}{
        shape=coordinate,
        for current and siblings={anchor=north}
      }{}
    }
  },
}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [$\Omega$, nice empty nodes
    [[G][B, cut]]
    [, cut, % calign=child, calign child=2 % an alternative to "calign with current" below
      [H]
      [, calign=last, calign with current
        [A]
        [R]
      ]
      [ceteri, cut, cut=0.3]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!